# Add a new field to a state array of objects

Tags: reactjs

I'm saving these objects from the api in the rules state, I need to add a new field called editable for each object inside that state. Tried this but is not doing anything.

```
componentDidMount() {
    Api.getRules(this.state.brand,
                this.state.model,
                this.state.version,
                this.state.minYear,
                this.state.maxYear,
                this.state.minKm,
                this.state.maxKm,
                this.state.page + 1,
                this.state.rowsPerPage).then((data) => {
      if (data) {
        this.setState({
          rules: data.body,
        });
      }
    });
    this.addEditableField();
    
  }

addEditableField = async () => {
    let teste = this.state.rules
    teste.map((rule)=>{rule["editable"]=false})
    await this.setState({ rules: teste })
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
if (data) {
    this.setState({
        rules: data.body,
    });
}
```

to

```
if (data) {
    this.setState({
        // this dumps all of the rule properties into a new object and
        // adds the new fields at the end of it
        rules: data.body.map(rule => ({...rule, editable: false })),
    });
}
```

`addEditableField` isn't an async method. It's not doing an ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing some problems in your implementation

- `addEditableField` is being called from a wrong place. Because this method will be called before you get the response from the backend. So once after the response is being fetched only the state will get updated with the actual response without `editable` field.
- Not returning anything from `taste.map` inside `addEditableField`
- Setting the same `rules` which is being obtained from state again in the state

Try calling the `addEditableField` once after the response is being fetched i.e., inside `Api.getRules(....).then()` like below

```
Api.getRules(this.state.brand,
  this.state.model,
  this.state.version,
  this.state.minYear,
  this.state.maxYear,
  this.state.minKm,
  this.state.maxKm,
  this.state.page + 1,
  this.state.rowsPerPage).then((data) => {
  if (data) {
    addEditableField(data.body);
  }
});

addEditableField = async(rules) => {
  let teste = rules.map((rule) => {
    rule["editable"] = false;
    return rule;
  });
  this.setState({
    rules: teste
  })
}
```

`addEditableField` method can also be simplified like below

```
addEditableField = async(rules) => {
  this.setState({
    rules: rules.map(rule => ({
      ...rule,
      editable: false
    }))
  })
}
```